# in the initialize of a ruby class, what is the difference between @name or self.name?

Tags: ruby

I know it makes sense to use self.name, but what does @name mean in the following code?

```
class NewGame < Game
  attr_accessor :name
  def initialize(name, options={})
    super
    self.name = name
  end

  def add_game(name)
     @name = name
  end
end
```

Is that even legit? Did I made a mistake?

Comment: You cannot have nGame as a name for a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@name` is an instance variable which may be accessed like a private member of a class instance.

`self.name` is a method call on the self object, if it is not explicitly defined you will get a NoMethodError.

I will go forward and explain that writing `attr_accessor :weight` in your class is the same as:

```
def weight=(v)
  @weight = v
end

def weight
  @weight
end
```

Comment: hmm... still don't understand what's the difference between self.name and @name. Can you explain a little further please?

Comment: @tips: You know what the difference between a variable and a function is? Yes? Then you have it. No? You should consult a basic introduction to programming

Comment: oh my bad, i got it now. self.name is calling the function setting the @name.